# Is there a way to make this MergeSort algorithm more efficient?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

So I have this algorithm for MergeSort, and I need to reduce the number of compares. I'm not allowed to use any extra data structures other than the ones I already have. I'm completely stumped as to how I can make this more efficient. Can anyone help?

```
int compares = 0;

// Merge two sorted subarrays arr[low .. mid] and arr[mid + 1 .. high]
void Merge(int arr[], int aux[], int low, int mid, int high)
{
    int k = low, i = low, j = mid + 1;

    // While there are elements in the left and right runs
    while (i <= mid && j <= high)
    {
        if (arr[i] <= arr[j])
            aux[k++] = arr[i++];
            compares++;
        else
            aux[k++] = arr[j++];
    }

    // Copy remaining elements
    while (i <= mid)
        aux[k++] = arr[i++];

    // No need to copy the second half

    // copy back to the original array to reflect sorted order
    for (int i = low; i <= high; i++)
        arr[i] = aux[i];
}

// Sort array arr [low..high] using auxiliary array aux
void MergeSort(int arr[], int aux[], int low, int high)
{
    // Base case
    if (high == low)    // if run size == 1
        return;

    // find mid point
    int mid = (low + ((high - low) >> 1));

    // recursively split runs into two halves until run size == 1,
    // then merge them and return back up the call chain

    MergeSort(arr, aux, low, mid);      // split / merge left  half
    MergeSort(arr, aux, mid + 1, high); // split / merge right half

    Merge(arr, aux, low, mid, high);    // merge the two half runs
}
```

Comment: If the sort is actually a merge sort, it will be O(n lg n) compares. What “compares” should be reduced?

Comment: Note that your `Merge()` function does not count all the item comparisons it performs.  It updates variable `compares` only when `arr[i] <= arr[j]` evaluates true, but that is a comparison regardless of its result.  Is there any chance that you have misunderstood the issue you are supposed to correct, and that this is it?

Comment: You could make the algorithm more efficient (but not reduce the number of item comparisons), by avoiding the step of copying the data back from the auxiliary array, except possibly at the end.  Instead, flip back and forth between which array is considered main and which auxiliary as you ascend back up from the bottom of the recursion.

Comment: Sorry, I should've clarified this, but the only compares I'm supposed to count are those between array accesses.

Answer (score 3):

There are some problems in your code:

- the `Merge` function is incorrect: the remaining elements from the right array are not copied to the `aux` array, which is fine (*No need to copy the second half*), but the final loop that copies the element back to `arr` should stop at `i < k` instead of running to `i <= high`
- The `compares` counter is only incremented if the comparison yields true.
- The `else` clause is a syntax error because there are 2 statements after the `if` that are not grouped as a block.

Here is a corrected version:

```
int compares = 0;

// Merge two sorted subarrays arr[low .. mid] and arr[mid + 1 .. high]
void Merge(int arr[], int aux[], int low, int mid, int high) {
    int k = low, i = low, j = mid + 1;

    // While there are elements in the left and right runs
    while (i <= mid && j <= high) {
        compares++;
        if (arr[i] <= arr[j])
            aux[k++] = arr[i++];
        else
            aux[k++] = arr[j++];
    }

    // Copy remaining elements
    while (i <= mid)
        aux[k++] = arr[i++];

    // No need to copy the second half

    // copy back to the original array to reflect sorted order
    for (int i = low; i < k; i++)
        arr[i] = aux[i];
}

// Sort array arr [low..high] using auxiliary array aux
void MergeSort(int arr[], int aux[], int low, int high) {
    // Base case
    if (high == low)    // if run size == 1
        return;

    // find mid point
    int mid = low + ((high - low) >> 1);

    // recursively split runs into two halves until run size == 1,
    // then merge them and return back up the call chain

    MergeSort(arr, aux, low, mid);      // split / merge left  half
    MergeSort(arr, aux, mid + 1, high); // split / merge right half

    Merge(arr, aux, low, mid, high);    // merge the two half runs
}
```

Reducing the number of comparison is not possible in the general case but if the array is known to have substantial portions that are already sorted, an extra initial comparison may allow for a substantial reduction in the total number of comparisons:

```
int compares = 0;

// Merge two sorted subarrays arr[low .. mid] and arr[mid + 1 .. high]
void Merge(int arr[], int aux[], int low, int mid, int high) {
    int k = low, i = low, j = mid + 1;

    // Extra comparison to improve special case of sorted arrays
    if (high - low > 7) {
        compares++;
        if (arr[mid] <= arr[j])
            return;
    }
    // While there are elements in the left and right runs
    while (i <= mid && j <= high) {
        compares++;
        if (arr[i] <= arr[j])
            aux[k++] = arr[i++];
        else
            aux[k++] = arr[j++];
    }

    // Copy remaining elements
    while (i <= mid)
        aux[k++] = arr[i++];

    // No need to copy the second half

    // copy back to the original array to reflect sorted order
    for (int i = low; i < k; i++)
        arr[i] = aux[i];
}
```